# Xpath from next page to scrapy in Stack Overflow

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl Stack Overflow with scrapy, but I'm not clear enough to make the rule to get next page. I don't know if the XPath I choose is right also.

He follows the code:

```
class StackCrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'stack_crawler'
    allowed_domains = ['stackoverflow.com']
    start_urls = [
        'http://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=newest'
    ]
    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('div[@class="pager fl"]/a[@class="page-numbers next"]/@href',)),
             callback='parse_item', follow=True)
    ]
```

Could someone who understand scrapy an XPath help me to get next page from the following page (http://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=newest) and add it to the rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to select root element `//` then go to `span` containing class `page-numbers next` and text `next` then go to it parent `..` which is `a` tag.

```
//span[@class="page-numbers next"]/../@href
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use `//a[@rel="next"]/@href`?